# convert string on form 2012,12,06,18,00,00 to create new gregorian calendar

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

Hi I have the following xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<share>
    <item>
        <name>Ericsson B</name>
        <currentRate>80.69</currentRate>
        <changeToday>-0.51</changeToday>
        <changeTodayPercent>-0.52</changeTodayPercent>
            <timeUpdated>2012,12,06,18,00,00</timeUpdated>
     </item>
    </share>
```

And I can read every variable and put them in an arraylist, all **EXCEPT** the "timeUpdated" variable that I can't manage to convert from string on the form "2012,12,06,18,00,00" to put into a new gregorian calendar like below

```
 GregorianCalendar updated = new GregorianCalendar(2012,12,06,16,30,55);
```

So my question how do I convert a String on the form "2012,12,06,16,30,55" to be able to put into

GregorianCalendar updated = new GregorianCalendar("My converted calendar string");

If you wonder here is my xmlparser

```
public AllSharesOnStockMarket(){

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("hejsan");
        System.out.println(parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));


        allShareHoldingsOnStockMarket.get(i).setName(parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
        tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(parser.getValue(e, KEY_CURRENTRATE));
        allShareHoldingsOnStockMarket.get(i).setCurrentRate(tempDouble);
        tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(parser.getValue(e, KEY_CHANGETODAY));
        allShareHoldingsOnStockMarket.get(i).setCurrentRate(tempDouble);
        tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(parser.getValue(e, KEY_CHANGETODAYPERCENT));
        allShareHoldingsOnStockMarket.get(i).setChangeTodayPercent(tempDouble);

        String dateToConvert = parser.getValue(e, KEY_TIMEUPDATED);//Need to convert this into a date so I can put into 
        allShareHoldingsOnStockMarket.get(i).setTimeUpdated("My Converted Date String That is the converted dateToConvert String");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as

```
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss").parse("2012,12,06,18,00,00");
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
    gc.setTime(date);
```

Comment: Yep, looks like that should do it although the `SimpleDateFormat` string should be `"yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm,ss"` (capital `HH` for 24-hour clock).

Comment: Right, will fix now, though it works on parse with hh just like HH - Thu Dec 06 18:00:00 EET 2012

Comment: Interesting, I didn't expect it to. I suspect using `format(...)` instead of `parse(...)` to do the reverse wouldn't work in the expected way though.